# Execute Sikuli script from AppleScript

Tags: applescript, sikuli

How do you execute a Sikuli script from an AppleScript?

Comment: The more relevant questions is: why are you asking questions on SO about Applescript and then deleting the question as well as the answer you wanted?

Comment: @songdogtech: because with those I etheir figure it out on my own or use another method so there really isn't any point of the question any more.

Comment: "...so there really isn't any point of the question any more" Yes there is. There are more reasons to keep the question and answer posted than there are to delete it once you found an answer. If you asked it, then chances are someone else has asked, or will ask, the same question or something like it. Besides, maybe someone has a better of achieving what you want than what you found. The point of SO is to create a massive database of questions and answers, no matter how big or small.

Comment: As Philip says, SO is a community that works on collaboration to build a collection of information. And I think you'll eventually find that questions are always much more interesting and valuable than answers, correct or incorrect as answers may be. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to execute shell commands from AppleScript:

```
do shell script ("/Applications/Sikuli-IDE.app/sikuli-ide.sh -r xxxx.sikuli --args a1 a2 a3")
```

See the "command line tool" documentation here: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/download.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Sikuli and it doesn't appear to be a scriptable application, so the short answer here is "You can't". At the same time, you can try interface scripting to kludge your way through it, but that's always wonky.

But to address another aspect of your question: Do you know about Dictionaries in Applescript? If an application is scriptable with Applescript, the Dictionary will tell you everything it is capable of. They are a required part of an AS implementation and can tell you in a matter of minutes almost everything you need to know (though each application carries their own caveats).

Comment: Yes, I do know about dictionaries.  Thanks!